# rails: get uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter everytime I try to run my specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, activesupport, railtie

I use both `rake spec` and `rspec spec/` trying to run my rspec tests, but I get the following error:

```
/home/XXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:49:in `initialize': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter (NameError)
  from /home/XXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:364:in `new'
  from /home/XXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:364:in `config'
  from /home/XXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:123:in `config'
  from /home/XXX/proj/candiru/config/application.rb:26:in `<class:Application>'
  from /home/XXX/proj/candiru/config/application.rb:11:in `<module:Candiru>'
```

It's weird because this file (`config/application.rb`) is loaded when I start the rails server and rails console, without any problems.

The "suspicious" line is: `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor","assets","bower_components")`, and if I comment it out, the next similar configuration line will marked as the error line.

Do you have any guess why this error is thrown?

Comment: In your gemfile, are you added a simple formatter gem? And if so, is it in a specific bundler group?

Comment: Actually, did you add anything to config/env/test.rb that could cause this issue?

Comment: The answer for both questions is no... Actually I didn't change anything special for test env...